# He taught me how to swim/ride

Tags: word-usage

Is "how" optional in such sentences?

"He taught me how to ride a bicycle/how to swim."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure: [ *"teach" + somebody + "to" + base form verb* ] (without "how") has two possible interpretations, so it depends on your intention.

One meaning is to teach someone a method for doing something.

The other meaning is teaching someone that *they should do something they already know how to do*, like in driving school, your instructor might *teach you to* use a turn signal before turning, or *teach you to* turn on your high beams when driving on an unlit highway alone at night.

These are both things that you obviously already know *how* to do, but you might not have known *to do them* in those circumstances.

Comment: so "teach to do" without "how"  has two meanings to teach somebody to do something with or without previous knowledge/skills. But "teach somebody how to do something"  with "how" means you are teaching the person who already has some skills, it can't be used if the person has no  skills. Right?

Comment: @AntoniaA Close. Teaching with "how" means they didn't know how to do that thing before, like *how to swim*, or *how to speak English*. Teaching without "how", depending on the context, either means the same as with "how", OR it means teaching someone when to do something or that they should do something they already know how to do.

Answer (score 4):

For the most part, yes. the "how" is optional. But there are subtle differences.

If you couldn't  swim until he taught you then either sentence will do, but the first is a little better.

If you already knew how to splash around and not sink and he taught you some techniques that improved your swimming you might say he taught you "how to swim", with an implied "how to swim properly".

In either case the extra "how" suggests to me that he taught you something about the principles involved, not just the act.

Comment: If I didn't know how to swim until he taught me, do you mean the sentence without "how" is better?

Comment: In that sentence, which starts asserting your inability, the "how" is OK. Then it does not carry the suggestion that  he taught you to do it better.